# VueJS default/starting a value ina list of searched terms

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Trying to make a search plugin using Vue and I'm having a problem with adding a starting/default value to the list of options.  If I comment out the pair or template lines involving the start prop the rest of it works fine, but nothing renders if I leave them in.

Component Code:

```
Vue.component('search', {
props: {
    type: String, 
    hidein: String, 
    start: {
        type: Object,
        default: null
    }
},
//props: ['type', 'hidein', 'start'],

data: function () {
    return {
        search: "",
        select: "",
        results: [],
    };
},

template: '<div @load="loaded"><input :id="hidein" type="text" v-model="search" @keyup="updateList">'+
'<input type="hidden" :name="hidein" v-model="select" class="form-control">'+
'<div v-if="start">Current: <span @click="select=start.id" :class="{\'label label-success\':(select==start.id)}>'+
'+ {{start.name}}</span></div>'+
'<div v-if="results.length">Do you mean:<ul>'+
'<li v-for="result in results" :key="result.id"><span @click="select=result.id" :class="{\'label label-success\':(select==result.id)}">'+
'+ {{result.name}}</span></li>'+
'</ul></div></div>',

methods: {
    updateList: function(e) {
        var response = [];
        console.log("search: "+this.search);
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/api/search/"+this.type,
            data: { key: this.search }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            this.results = msg;
            console.log(this.results);
        }.bind(this));
    }, 
    loaded: function () {
        this.select=!!this.start ? this.start.id : null;
    }
},
});
```

Component Call:

```
<search type="ships" hidein="ship_id" ></search>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? (Besides the hacked together template, that's hopefully a completely separate issue with the pipeline I'm having)

Comment: BTW you can use back quotes ` to define multi-line template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a missing `"` here

```
:class="{\'label label-success\':(select==start.id)}
```

But also, please, use a template literal to make your life easier.

```
  `<div @load="loaded"><input :id="hidein" type="text" v-model="search" @keyup="updateList">
    <input type="hidden" :name="hidein" v-model="select" class="form-control">
    <div v-if="start">
      Current: 
      <span @click="select=start.id" :class="{'label label-success':(select==start.id)}">
        {{start.name}}
      </span>
    </div>
    <div v-if="results.length">
      Do you mean:
      <ul>
        <li v-for="result in results" :key="result.id">
          <span @click="select=result.id" :class="{'label label-success':(select==result.id)}">
            {{result.name}}
          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>`
```

Comment: Well, I suppose it's a good thing it was something small and stupid.  Thanks.

Comment: @watchwood been there!

Comment: I don't suppose you have any thoughts on why `{{start.name}}` wouldn't spit anything out, but `{{start}}` spits out the whole payload?  (including the name)

Comment: @watchwood Would need to see the data structure. Can you set up a test on a fiddle or pen?